# Adding a UI-Bootstrap Element to DOM inside Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular and I am trying to figure out the following problem.  When the user highlights some text, I would like a ui-bootstrap popover to surround the highlighted text.  Since this would manipulate the DOM I think I need to use a directive for this.  I was able to successfully implement a simpler version of this problem here

```
app.directive('selectOnClick', function ($window) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function () {

                var span = document.createElement("span");
                span.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                span.style.color = "green";

                if (window.getSelection) {
                    var sel = window.getSelection();
                    if (sel.rangeCount) {
                        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                        range.surroundContents(span);
                        sel.removeAllRanges();
                        sel.addRange(range);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In the above code I am able to surround the highlighted text with a `span` tag.  However I would like to instead use a ui-bootstrap popover.  I tried replacing the `span` part with `var popover=angular.element("<a href=#' uib-popover='hello' popover-title='hello'></a>");` but this did not work.  Am I on the right track or would this approach not work with a ui-bootstrap element?

**UPDATED**

Here is my attempt at adding the the popover element

```
app.directive('selectOnClick', function ($window, $compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function () {

                var popover=angular.element("<a href=#' uib-popover='hello' popover-title='hello'></a>");

                if (window.getSelection) {
                    var sel = window.getSelection();
                    if (sel.rangeCount) {
                        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
                        range.surroundContents($compile(popover));
                        sel.removeAllRanges();
                        sel.addRange(range);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately I am getting the error `TypeError: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` on the line `range.surroundContents($compile(popover));`  So I suppose `$compile(popover)` is not the correct type.  Can it be converted to `Node` type somehow?

Comment: Anything you insert that has directives in it needs to run through `$compile()`. `angular.element` only creates a jQuery like object but won't do the compiling

Comment: You can pot that element in the DOM and toggle it using `ngIf` - Don't over-complicate things when you can use native angularjs directives - You can also use the `popover-enable` attribute to enable/disable it

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't think I can do that since the element needs to be put where the text is highlighted.  We don't know where the text will be highlighted beforehand